# JSTL get object from session

Tags: jsp, session, struts2, jstl

I have put an object in the session:

```
session.setAttribute("userDTO", currentUser);
```

And I am trying to display it using EL. I have succeeded with scriplets (proving that the object is set in the session fine).

Code in JSP:

```
<body>
    <% UserDTO userdto=(UserDTO)session.getAttribute("userDTO"); %>
    <%=userdto.getUsername() %>
    Username from session:<c:out value="${sessionScope.userDTO.username }"/>
</body>
```

The scriplets display the username but nothing is displayed after "Username from session:". Why?

**UserDTO class:**

```
public class UserDTO {
    private int ID;
    private String email;
    private boolean emailConfirmed;
    private String username;
    private String role;
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    public boolean isEmailConfirmed() {
        return emailConfirmed;
    }
    public void setEmailConfirmed(boolean emailConfirmed) {
        this.emailConfirmed = emailConfirmed;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you put it? What is the `session` variable, how did you initialize it?

Comment: You probably forgot to include the core library in your JSP. Please show us a minimal JSP reproducing the problem, from the very first line of it to it very last one. Also look at the generated HTML code (using "view page source" in the browser).

Comment: What is the prefix `c` in your tag? Sow us `taglib` definition. Also define what libraries is used to support it.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet! I forgot to include the core library. Works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Put `jstl-x.x.jar` in lib folder or put dependency in maven.

**Step 2:** In `jsp` file

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
 ...
 <body>
     <% UserDTO userdto=(UserDTO)session.getAttribute("userDTO"); %>
     <%=userdto.getUsername() %>
     Username from session:<c:out value="${sessionScope.userDTO.username }"/>
      ...
 </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your JSP you can simply do it by using the expression (its called EL - expression language) -

```
<body>
  Username from session : ${sessionScope.currentUser}
</body>
```