# Is it not possible to directly invoke session.getAttribute() with EL?

Tags: jsp, el, session-scope

The value for 'email' is set within session scope using

```
session.setAttribute("email", "john@gmail.com").
```

To display the value later, the following code was used

`<c:out value='${session.getAttribute("email")}'> </c:out>`

This yielded no output on the screen. Note that the necessary packages were imported and that there is no error produced.

However, if I re-write using the scriptlet: `<% out.print(session.getAttribute("email")); %>`, I get my desired output.

Why doesn't `session.getAttribute()` work when using the EL expression?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSTL get object from session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225024/jstl-get-object-from-session)

Comment: Why are you trying to compare apples with oranges? Just use `${EMAIL}` (and lowercase that awkwardly all-capitalized name). And, please don't mix JSTL with EL. They are both entirely distinct. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Comment: @BalusC Could you elaborate a little more on your point of not mixing JSTL and EL? I have until now thought that they are complementary to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is why doesn't session.getAttribute() work when using the
>   JSTL tag?

The correct way of fetching a session attribute in a jsp via EL is

```
<c:out value='${sessionScope.EMAIL}'/>
```

You are messing up the JSTL & scriptlet code, you can try

```
email: <%= session.getAttribute("EMAIL") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In EL you access session variables using the `sessionScope` object like `${sessionScope.EMAIL}`.

Comment: That's great! Solves my problem. But just curious, why wouldn't the code I had written in the JSTL tag work? Where does the problem lie? As far as I know there wasn't any error in the code. Just no output.